# Limit number of words in the text box

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-designer, infopath2010

I am new to Info path, I know how to limit the no.of characters entered in to the text box using string-length function. But is there any way we can limit the number of Words entered in to an multiline text box.

For example a field which is asking to enter 10 words are lesser

Comment: You could check how many spaces there are and allow only 9 of them.

Comment: I tried using this string-length(.) - string-length(translate(., " ","")) > 10 but it allows me to type over 10 words

Comment: @David GM Can you explain me how can I do that.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I answered without looking at the tags - I thought I was browsing VBA. I cannot code in sharepoint/infopath. If it works in a similar way, what I would do is check the amount of spaces (can you get that to work? Debug and check with different numbers to see if it gives the right number). See this thing I googled for string manipulation http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2010/videos/infopath-substring-after-substring-before-functions.htm Maybe it can give you an idea - separate the string into substrings (1 per word) separated by the space. Then put them back together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer and wanted to share it

Set a Validation Rule for the field(textbox). In the condition select the "The expression" and type the below condition

```
string-length(field)-string-length(translate(field," ","")) <10
```

here field is the name of the textbox. And enter the text in the Screen Tip (Eg: Only lesser than 10 words) and click more option if you want ScreenTip and dialog box message.
For testing in the preview type more then 10 words and hit tab the dialogue box with Only lesser than 10 words will appear

Comment: I got an error on this, however I managed to get it working with : `string-length(.) - string-length(translate(., " ","")) > 10`

Answer (score 0):

Select the Text Box Properties

In `Display` tab

Check the check box for `Limit the Textbox to:` and enter the number for limiting the text box in that

Click `OK` button

Now the text box will allow only 10 characters alone